# T-SQL SELECT with GROUP BY id

Tags: sql, select, group-by

I have table with '**People**'

Columns

- ID
- Name
- Age

And table with '**Notes**':

Columns

- ID
- Text
- FK_Author

I want to select count of notes for all authors from people table and their name and age, but I want to group it by PERSON ID, not name. There are many situations when people have same name, but ID is obviously always different.

EXAMPLE (input)

**PEOPLE:**

```
╔════╦═══════╦═════╗
║ ID ║ NAME  ║ AGE ║
╠════╬═══════╬═════╣
║  1 ║ John  ║  12 ║
║  2 ║ Annie ║  29 ║
║  3 ║ John  ║  44 ║
╚════╩═══════╩═════╝
```

**NOTES:**

```
╔════╦═══════╦═══════════╗
║ ID ║ TEXT  ║ FK_AUTHOR ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║ 'aaa' ║         1 ║
║  2 ║ 'aaa' ║         1 ║
║  3 ║ 'aaa' ║         2 ║
║  4 ║ 'aaa' ║         2 ║
║  5 ║ 'aaa' ║         3 ║
╚════╩═══════╩═══════════╝
```

**Expected result:**

```
╔═══════╦═════╦════════════╗
║ NAME  ║ AGE ║ TOTALCOUNT ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════╣
║ John  ║  12 ║          2 ║
║ Annie ║  29 ║          2 ║
║ John  ║  44 ║          1 ║
╚═══════╩═════╩════════════╝
```

When I select data I have to group by Name too if I want to select this column because if I dont, I get error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you want to get all records from table `People`, you need to join it with `Notes` by using `LEFT JOIN` so any user without any record on `Notes` will be included in the list with thev value of `totalCount` with zero.

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.Name, a.Age,
        COUNT(b.FK_Author) totalCount
FROM    People a
        LEFT JOIN Notes b
            ON a.ID = b.FK_Author
GROUP   BY a.ID, a.Name, a.Age
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81929/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦═══════╦═════╦════════════╗
║ ID ║ NAME  ║ AGE ║ TOTALCOUNT ║
╠════╬═══════╬═════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║ John  ║  12 ║          2 ║
║  2 ║ Annie ║  29 ║          2 ║
║  3 ║ John  ║  44 ║          1 ║
╚════╩═══════╩═════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: It is wrong answer, like i said I don't ant to group by name/age. This column can be same for diferent people

Comment: NO. You are wrong. This query will give you the result you need. Remember that you are including `ID` on the `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: if you don't want the `ID`, remove the column name from the `SELECT` clause only, not on the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT P.ID,P.Name,P.Age,COUNT(N.ID)
FROM People P 
INNER JOIN Notes N ON N.FK_Author = P.ID
GROUP BY P.ID,P.Name,P.age
```

Comment: You have to group by all the fields that you want to display in the select, but since you first group by ID they will all be different.

Answer (score 3):

you can use subquery also to complete this task as-

```
select people.Name,people.Age,(select count(notes.id) 
                                 from notes 
                                where notes.FK_Author= people.id)
from people;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also get the count from the Notes table first and then left join with the People table like below.

[**Fiddle-demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81929/2) (thanks to J W for the fiddle)

```
select name, age, Notate_Count
from People p left join (
        select fk_author, count(*) Notate_Count
        from Notes 
        group by fk_author ) x
     on p.Id = x.fk_author
order by name --Ordering by name here, change as required

|  NAME | AGE | NOTATE_COUNT |
------------------------------
| Annie |  29 |            2 |
|  John |  44 |            1 |
|  John |  12 |            2 |
```